# How to curl structure

Tags: php, rest, curl

How do I use curl within my php to initialize this query from a web application I am interested in.

```
$ curl https://api.airtable.com/v0/appQmOEr6c6AV4X47/foo \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY"
```

I am more used to using curl some thing like this

```
// Make call with cURL
$session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$json = curl_exec($session);
$string = print_r($json,true);
$result = json_decode($string,true);
```

Why is the $ seperate from the `curl` and what is the `-H` doing?
I tried Google and the other `curl` related topics in www.stackoverflow.com

I found a solution here: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
And applied it to get this code, worked.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.airtable.com/v0/appQmOEr6c6AV4X47/foo');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Have you consulted the curl man page?

Comment: `curl https://api.airtable.com/v0/appQmOEr6c6AV4X47/foo \ -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY"` should be called from the command line of a system with cURL installed.

Comment: Why don't you use `file_get_contents`?

Comment: So I have to do it outside of php?

Comment: ">So I have to do it outside of php?" Why don't you tell us what you're trying to accomplish. Right now, I can't see why you need to use PHP for this, instead of just using the curl command-line tool.

Comment: @CharlesHaughey You apparently don't understand that the first snippet is not PHP, but a command line string like you would enter it in a shell. The `$` is often used to denote exactly that (and isn't part of the actual command), as most shell prompts end in `$` before the area where you enter your command.

Comment: The `-H` option is analogous to the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option in PHP.

Comment: Correct I don't understand, that why I'm asking. I'm trying to query an Api from AirTable. To do this I usually build a php script, including in it curl commands as shown in my example above and then have a cron job automate it. Then if a match appears I send an SMS via a Gateway I am signed up to. AirTable Docs are mostly referenced in Curl in the style of the top part of my example above and I just don't understand how I can automate it outside of php. Hence the question....... and now I am minus 1 for asking!!! I will read up on the suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ curl https://api.airtable.com/v0/appQmOEr6c6AV4X47/foo \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY"
```

This is an example of using a Unix-like (Linux) shell to run [the curl binary](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl).  `$` is a convention that indicates that you're seeing a shell prompt, and that the user is non-privileged (i.e. not root).

```
// Make call with cURL
$session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$json = curl_exec($session);
$string = print_r($json,true);
$result = json_decode($string,true);
```

This is an example of a snippet of PHP code that uses [the PHP curl library](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

---

Both of these use [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/) a C library.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.airtable.com/v0/appQmOEr6c6AV4X47/Tasks?maxRecords=3&view=Main%20View");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$con = json_decode($server_output);
```